Why do most survivor groups in France use manual-action firearms?
While watching The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon, which is set in France, I noticed an interesting contrast in the weapons used by different survivor groups. Most survivor groups who use firearms, including those Daryl joins (i.e., the "good guys"), rely on manual-action firearms (lever-action, bolt-action, pump-action, break-action, and the like). (The exception is the antagonist faction Pouvoir Du Vivant, aka Power of the Living, which controls most of Paris under Genet's leadership and primarily uses modern semi-automatic and automatic weapons.)
This differs significantly from the original The Walking Dead series set in the US, where survivors, both good guys and bad guys, typically use modern semi-automatic and automatic firearms. These weapons are generally more practical for survival, offering advantages like larger magazine/clip capacity, faster reload times, and higher fire rates - making them more effective against both zombies and hostile humans.
I'm curious about the reasoning behind this choice. Could it be for aesthetic (though not realistic) purposes, adding a "wild west" flair to the European setting?
Or is it perhaps meant to reflect reality? Given the differences in gun culture and regulations between France and the US, I wonder if manual-action weapons would actually be more accessible to French survivors in an apocalyptic scenario, compared to the widespread availability of semi-automatic and automatic weapons in the US shown in the original series.
Why do most survivor groups in France use manual-action firearms?

I'm going to answer using legal information so it may take some time because I'm not an expert in the subject; just a sport firearms owner.

Now, if these survivors decided to move to Switzerland, they may have a bigger array of firearms to choose from, seeing that you can legally acquire full auto firearms in some Swiss cantons (although I'm not Swiss so I cannot say for certain). That, and each person who did their military service also has the choice to purchase their service rifle.

Which weapon is more practical for a survival situation isn't really all that relevant in a scenario where civilization has broken down and you use whatever you can find.

@Flater That's exactly my point—given France's different gun culture and regulations, I'm curious whether French survivors would have easier access to manual-action guns compared to semi-automatic or automatic weapons, unlike their American counterparts.

A comment because I can't prove it: this choice may have been a world building decision. The use of manual action firearms reflecting the loss of technology and "abundance" while still providing the story the ability to move the plot forward without more difficult to explain (and on average bloodier) hand-to-hand action. In other words, this choice may have had nothing at all to do with France, but instead was designed to further identify the apocalyptic setting.

You are right on the last paragraph: most (but not all) semi-automatic firearms are legally harder to acquire when compared to the other ones (pump action, lever action, bolt action, single shot, etc.).
In France, every firearm (and any other weapon for that instance) can be put in 4 distinct categories, according to this page from service-public.fr. I'm going to keep it simple because the actual laws on firearms are very lengthy and complex, and it gets harder because there are appendixes with firearms which are put in a lower or higher category (sometimes with no apparent explanation beside its rarity).

Category A: These are all the weapons and their equipment that are unavailable to the average Joe. It can range from firearms with full auto capability, magazine capacity above 30 rounds for rifles, magazine capacity above 20 rounds for handguns, aircrafts, tanks, nuclear weapons, nuclear submarines, weapons that were modified to become semi-automatic only but initially had full auto capability (previously available but recently banned since 2021). As far as I know, only gunsmiths who acquired proper accreditations are allowed to have them (beside the military I suppose).

Category B: A huge majority of the semi-automatic weapons (handguns, rifles, shotguns) are within this category (as well as anything that doesn't fit in category C, such as bolt/lever action rifles with a capacity of more than 11 rounds), which you can only purchase after having spent at least 1 year as a sport shooter within an FFTir (Fédération Française de Tir, French Shooting Federation) affiliated shooting range club, learning the proper firearms manipulation and safety rules, and after passing a questionnaire, doing 3 controlled shooting sessions under the monitoring of a range officer (with 2 months between sessions). Only then will your shooting club deliver a paper that says you are deemed qualified to acquire a category B firearm. At this point, you can start doing the legal procedures to acquire the required authorizations (back then you had to send a filled form with several legal documents by envelope to your local prefect, but since 2024, you have to create an Internet account on the proper website, which I won't mention because we are not on Law Stack Exchange). And even after being a legal owner of category B firearms, you have to renew your authorization every 5 years, otherwise your firearms will get confiscated. And if you stop going to the range for too long or stop renewing your annual membership every year, your firearms will also be confiscated. It's not exactly difficult but it's not a trivial thing to do, and I have heard of many sport shooters who expressed being discouraged in owning category B because of the formalities. Also, you can only own up to 15 category B firearms as a civilian.

Category C: Beside category D, it's the other easiest category to acquire. It includes bolt action rifles, lever actions with a capacity up to 10+1 (10 in the magazine and 1 in the chamber). There's also pump shotguns (although I don't know the authorised ammo capacity), as well as some semi-automatic weapons but with very limited capacity (2+1 for semi-automatic carbine and shotguns).  All you need to do is have a sport shooter membership (either FFTir or Ball-trap (clay pigeon shooting)), or acquire a hunting license. Once you acquire your firearms and ammunitions, your only legal obligation is to store them separately, ensuring the firearms are not immediately usable (by removing the bolt from bolt action rifle for example, or putting them in a safe), although you are not legally authorised to shoot anymore if you acquired them with a sport shooter membership and didn't renew it, and you can no longer purchase ammo either in that case. I cannot say for hunting license because I'm not a hunter. There are no limits to how many category C firearms you can own. Category C also includes airguns with a power above 20 joules by the way. If you have a collector title, you can also acquire category C but no ammo (logically speaking, when you collect, you're not a shooter, so you don't shoot).

Category D: This is basically everything else. It goes from airguns below 20 joules, to black powder firearms, to collector firearms (patented before the 1900s), to the "firearms put in a lower category", to knives, etc. You can acquire them as long as you are legally an adult.


Along with the types of firearms, some calibres are also available to purchase only if you are allowed to acquire category B firearms (such as .223 Remington and its NATO equivalent the 5.56x45mm), whereas some others can be used in both category C and B firearms (such as the much bigger .308 Winchester and its NATO equivalent the 7.62×51mm). Those are referred as "calibres maudits" (cursed calibres). The full list is the following, as per the second link from this answer, category B4°:

a) Calibre 7,62 × 39 ;
b) Calibre 5,56 × 45 ;
c) Calibre 5,45 × 39 ;
d) Calibre 12,7 × 99 ;
e) Calibre 14,5 × 114 ;

Seeing that category C weapons are much easier to acquire, and France is (from what I know) known to have at least a million hunters and only 200,000 FFTir shooters as of 2024 (see in the top right corner), it's no surprise that a huge majority of the depicted firearms would be those of category C, because those are the ones you are most likely to find inside a French household. Besides, not every FFTir shooters have taken the decision to acquire category B firearms either, which make it even less likely to find them (unless you decide to specifically loot armouries I suppose, but they usually are highly secured to prevent robberies).

France currently has 251,963 FFTir sport shooters member as of November 2024.

I don't know how many Ball-Trap shooters there are, nor how many professionals (security companies, police, gendarmerie, armée française, how many gunsmiths/armouries) have access to firearms so I cannot comment on that.

Disclaimer: When I say "loot armouries", it's within the logic of a collapsed society as depicted usually in zombie apocalypse settings. Similarly, French sport shooters and hunters are not legally allowed to point a firearm at anyone at the risk of being banned, having your license revoked, the firearm(s) confiscated and being added to a list of people who are forbidden from ever owning weapons of any kind.

Well done. I am really astonished that the makers took this into account instead of assuming the omnipresence of weapons as found in the USA.

@Tode In a way, they could have hand waved it away with "black market illegal weapons" but yeah, it does add to the realism.

"those are the ones you are most likely to find inside a French household" and compared to the US, you are extremely unlikely to find any kind of firearm in a French household. There are over 300 million firearms in the US and among them millions or tens of millions of (semi-)automatic firearms. In France, there are less than 3 million firearms, and less than 800 000 of them in category B.

@jcaron Yes, and on top of that, you also add the fact firearms owners tend to have more than one, which further reduces the likelihood (i.e. it's not proportionally distributed among the 68 millions French citizens). A huge majority of my acquaintances are neither interested in shooting sport nor hunting, but a friend has a huge collection of hundreds by himself.

Same here in Germany - about 950 000 people own about 5 million firearms (no full auto allowed, so mostly break action shotguns and semi automatic rifles with small magazines for hunting, and semi automatic pistols and revolvers and target pistols for recreational and competitive shooting. Also no open/public carry and strict requirements for storage, so to equip yourself after the apocalypse you'd need to crack a few gun safes first).
